# Como asociar un input tipo file múltiple al id del registro de la fila donde se selecciona las imágenes?

Tags: php, laravel, input

Estoy llenando una tabla dinámicamente en la cual agrego datos de un producto el cual se le deben de cargar 4 fotos, como le indico al momento de guardar que fotos son de cada registro?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola Yussef, gracias por responder, te muestro como esta declarado mi input tipo file

```
<td class="text-left"><input class='form-control-file text-danger'  type="file"  size='50' name='fotos[]' multiple></td>
```

creo esta como dices, pero al guardar el registro el FileBag me trae solo un array con todas las fotos. Aqui esta el DD() que hago del request

```
files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#51 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "fotos" => array:5 [▼
        0 => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#33 ▶}
        1 => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#34 ▶}
        2 => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#35 ▶}
        3 => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#36 ▶}
        4 => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#37 ▶}
      ]
    ]
```

el problema es como asociar cada id de los equipos con las fotos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Debes colocar un `name` distinto a cada "input file" o colocar un name del tipo array haciendo `<input type="file" name="archivo[]">"`

Answer (score 0):

Hola Yussef con lo que me dijiste pude resolver el problema, solo que al Name del input le concatené el ID del equipo, porque solo con el Name[] metía todas las imágenes en un mismo arreglo.

```
<td><input class='form-control-file text-danger'  type="file" name='fotos${mData.id}[]' multiple></td>
```

Luego en el controlador recorro el array de equipos y dentro de este recorro el array de las imágenes y le concateno el Id del equipo al array del File, así me quedo en el controlador

```
foreach ($request->fotosEquipo_id as $equipo) {
            foreach ($request->file('fotos'.$equipo) as $file) {
                echo ($file->getClientOriginalName());
            }
        }
```

y solucionado el problema que tenia, gracias una vez mas, mi pregunta no se entendia mucho pero me entendiste y diste en el clavo.